# generate random number using specific digits in javascript

Tags: javascript, random

In my program I want to generate 5 digit random number such the that contain only digits ( 1 to 7).

```
var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (11111 - 77777 + 1)) + 11111;
```

Using above code I got number between `11111` and `77777`. But how to generate the number that does not contain `0,8,9`  ? Is there any default method to generate this kind of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
len = 5
num = 0
while(len--)
    num = num * 10 + digits[Math.floor(Math.random() * digits.length)]
console.log(num)
```

This way you can easily select which digits to use.

Comment: In python(list) I use <code>random.sample(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'],5) </code>to do this.Is there any similar default function in js?

Comment: @mridul: `random.sample` returns non-repeating values, so you won't get `11111` from it. No, there's no such builtin in JS, `Math.random` is pretty much all you've got.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate each digit at a time, concatenate them then parseInt to get your result:

```
var str = '';
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  str += Math.floor(Math.random()*7) + 1;
}
var randnum = parseInt(str);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/abOLEXe/1/edit?js,console,output)

Explanation

`Math.random()` returns [0,1)

`Math.random() * 7` returns [0,7)

`Math.floor(...)` returns 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

`...+1` returns 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: Math.ceil(Math.random()*7)... +1 will create 8 with 0.99 by Math.random

Comment: `Math.random` returns a number in the range of [0,1). If it returns 0, `Math.ceil` will be 0, multiplied by 7 will be 0 which is out of the range required.

Comment: @SergeyKochetov No, it should be multiplied by 7 because that gives the range of `[0, 6]` and `+1` gives `[1, 7]`.

Comment: Code is changing so fast... with Math.ceil it should be 6, with Math.floor - 7 =)

Comment: Updated your jsbin btw, it was still pointing to the old one :)

Comment: Sorry about that, i added an explanation that should make it clear now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SergeyKochetov No, with `Math.ceil()` it should be multiplied by `7` as well, but then you would get a theoretical range of `[0, 7]` (the lower bound is not reached in most cases).